# Xcode Playground liveView: preview changes on keyboard shortcut

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using a Playground to speed up prototyping and the build/preview cycle. This works well so far, but liveView updates constantly with each small change to the code which is quite distracting. I would like the liveView to update via a keyboard shortcut when my changes are ready - is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode 8**

In the bottom left long click on play button and select manually run.

[image]

Open the Xcode preferences -> Key Binding and search Execute Playground. It's empty, but you can assign it anything.